# Implementing both English & Arabic user interfaces to Esri Geoportal Server?

Tags: esri-geoportal-server, internationalization, arabic

I am using ESRI Geoportal Server 1.2.2 and need to implement both English & Arabic user interfaces. For this I am maintaining separate resource file for both languages (gpt_en.properties and gpt_ar.properties).  As mentioned within the Localization help section of geoportal server,  I was able to change the UI texts to a desired language (English or Arabic) by configuring it within the gpt-faces-config.xml. This works fine. Now I am having the following queries.

Is there any setting with Geoportal Server which I can modify so that within the user interface itself I can switch between multiple languages ?

This should include the layout changes also (shifting UI elements left to right for Arabic).

Do i need to implement this programetically?

If so, then where will I get the required references?

Comment: It may be possible to do this in Esri Geoportal Server, but I don't know how. An alternative is to write your own UI which handles the internationalization. See my profile for a link to a stand-alone application I built on top of Esri Geoportal Server - you could use this approach to create the Arabic version of the UI.